# How to update sum during for loop in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop

Got stuck at this exercise.
The goal is to let the user input the type and number of coins added to the program, and count the total coins and amount of money the user has.

**update:**
I think I'm almost there, (sorted out the amount of money!) but my problem is that the total coins adds up badly after the second loop. (the sum is incorrect)

```
//硬貨の種類の合計
        int kindSum = 0;
        //硬貨の枚数の合計
        int amountSum = 0;

        //質問を10回繰り返し
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            //硬貨の種類の入力
            System.out.println(i + "回目。硬貨の種類を入力してください。");
            int kindInput = inputScanner.nextInt();
            //硬貨の枚数の入力
            System.out.println(i + "回目。硬貨の枚数を入力してください。");
            int amountInput = inputScanner.nextInt();

            kindSum = kindInput + myMoney.getAmount() + myMoney.addCoins(kindInput, amountInput);
            amountSum = amountInput + totalCoin + myMoney.getCount(kindInput);

            //足した合計を表示する(1回ずつ)
            System.out.println("硬貨の総枚数は" + kindSum +
                    "枚、総額は" + amountSum);
        }
```

I reckon I should be using something like `sum += sum + i` but when I use something like `kindSum += + kindInput + myMoney.getAmount();` the total just doubles up.

Would appreciate any advice, many thanks in advance.

---

The full code, if anyone is wondering-

```
class ManageCoin {

    //硬貨の種類
    int yen500 = 0;
    int yen100 = 0;
    int yen50 = 0;
    int yen10 = 0;

    //• addCoinsメソッドで硬貨を増やしたり減らしたりする
    //メソッドの引数は硬貨の種類と枚数
    public int addCoins(int kind, int count) {
        //種類を絞っていく
        switch (kind) {
        case 500:           //500出てきたら500円の数を増やす
            yen500 += count;
            break;
        case 100:
            yen100 += count;
            break;
        case 50:
            yen50 += count;
            break;
        case 10:
            yen10 += count;
            break;
        }
        return 0; //何もなかったら最初に戻る
    }

    //getCountメソッドで硬貨が何枚あるかを取得する
    //メソッドの引数は硬貨の種類
    public int getCount(int kind) {
        switch(kind) {
        case 500:           //500出たら500円の種類を特定
            return yen500;
        case 100:
            return yen100;
        case 50:
            return yen50;
        case 10:
            return yen10;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    //getAmountメソッドで硬貨の総額を取得する
    //メソッドの引数はなし
    public int getAmount() {
        return (yen500 * 500) + (yen100 * 100) +
                (yen50 * 50) + (yen10 * 10);
    }
```

```
ManageCoin myMoney = new ManageCoin();

        //初期値の硬貨＝財布
        myMoney.yen500 = 1;
        myMoney.yen100 = 4;
        myMoney.yen50 = 1;
        myMoney.yen10 = 4;

        //硬貨の総枚数と総額を表示する
        int totalCoin = myMoney.getCount(500) +
                myMoney.getCount(100) +
                myMoney.getCount(50) +
                myMoney.getCount(10);

        //①ユーザーに硬貨の種類と枚数を入力してもらう
        System.out.println("初期化の硬貨の総枚数は" + totalCoin +
                "枚、総額は" + myMoney.getAmount() + "円です。");

        //②入力したら硬貨の枚数と総額を表示する
        //入力を受け付ける
        Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        //入力の指示
        System.out.println("500円、100円、50円、10円から、");
        System.out.println("硬貨の種類と枚数を決めて数字で10回ずつ入力してください。");
        System.out.println("硬貨の枚数を増やしたり減らしたりすることもできます。");
        System.out.println();

        //硬貨の種類の合計
        int kindSum = 0;
        //硬貨の枚数の合計
        int amountSum = 0;

        //質問を10回繰り返し
        for (int count = 1; count <= 10; count++) {

            //硬貨の種類の入力
            System.out.println(count + "回目。硬貨の種類を入力してください。");
            int kindInput = inputScanner.nextInt();
            //硬貨の枚数の入力
            System.out.println(count + "回目。硬貨の枚数を入力してください。");
            int amountInput = inputScanner.nextInt();

            kindSum = kindInput + myMoney.getAmount() + myMoney.addCoins(kindInput, amountInput);
            amountSum = amountInput + totalCoin + myMoney.getCount(kindInput);

            //足した合計を表示する(1回ずつ)
            System.out.println("硬貨の総枚数は" + amountSum +
                    "枚、総額は" + kindSum);
        }

        //③①~②を10回繰り返す
        System.out.println("硬貨の総枚数は" + amountSum +
                "枚、総額は" + kindSum);
```

Comment: Why are you not using your `addCoins()` method?

Comment: Not `sum += sum + i;`.  Either `sum += i;` or  `sum = sum + i;`, but don't try to do both on the same line.  Otherwise ... everything doubles up.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thanks! The `kindSum` variable works okay right now. Don't know why I didn't opt to use that.